# IIS7 and DNS subdomain wildcard redirect

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-7

I want to reserve www.mysite.com for a particular directory and *.mysite.com to go to another directory.

When I've done this in the past, the wildcard pointed to the same directory as the main site.

As best I can explain it, here is what I have.

**DNS**

```
* (A) record
www (A) record
```

**IIS**

```
MySite.com 
- bound: www.mysite.com *The IP address
- directory: /inetpub/wwwroot/mysite

*.MySite.com 
- bound: mysite.com *The IP address
- directory: /inetpub/wwwroot/mysite_w
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be able to accomplish this correctly if you have two IP addresses on the server you are using. At this point in time, IIS cannot handle wild card addresses in host headers (this is a commonly requested feature), so you'll need to point www.mysite.com to one IP and *.mysite.com to the other in your DNS records. The in IIS you'll bind each site to it's respective IP address.

You need these two IP addresses because you cannot rely on host headers to differentiate between sites. If you cannot get two IPs on the box, you will not be able to accomplish this using IIS to drive your websites.

Comment: But, if I have several sites that require this, each one is going to need dual IP addresses in order to function, correct?  So for three sites, each with a wildcard subdomain, I will need 6 IP addresses.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It's a horrible way to go about things, but until IIS has support for wildcards there is other way to catch a wildcard DNS entry.

Comment: Finally talked my client to adding a LAMP server on their Rackspace  because of this issue. So maybe it will all work out in the end.